# Pull variables from a remote page

Tags: php, html, fopen

I am wanting to setup a script that fopen's or similar a remote php file with the output of say:

```
version= 1.1.0
date= 01/22/13
link= http://example.com/1.1.0
blah= blah
```

But I am wanting to remotely, turn this file into the corresponding variables in the local php script.

I have seen this done many of places, but can't seem to find a how-to on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"file" returns an array of lines.  Explode these on the "=" and assign to a variable variable.

```
<?
    $configLines = file('configfile.txt');
    foreach ($configLines as $av)
    {
        list ($a, $v) = explode('=', $av);
        $$a = $v;   
    }

?>
```

Comment: Note: If you have control over the config file then go with Ethan's answer.  If you don't have control over the config, then this will work:  FTM: "...If a value in the ini file contains any non-alphanumeric characters it needs to be enclosed in double-quotes (")...."

Comment: I think this is the best bet. Im using this with a script that will be used on many systems... So this seems to be the best option!

Answer (score 3):

you could make it into an ini file

```
[Current Release]
version=1.1.0
date="1/22/13"
```

Then in a file that will be requested by the server

```
$content = parse_ini_file('my_file.ini');
//JSON
echo json_encode($content);
```

Comment: Yep.. That is exactly what I was looking for! I knew it had to be simple, just did not know the function! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: very nice - I was not aware of the parse_ini_file function.  Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine that if you place the file below your web root, you could request the file via http

Comment: It doesn't work with URL be default.. I get this warning.. Warning: parse_ini_file() [function.parse-ini-file]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

Comment: Check your httpd.conf and php.ini, what code are you using to access the file? Also, you may want to post that as a new question.

Comment: Yeah i knew it has something to do with config giles.. But I am wanting something that is universally available without changing anything on the server. It is going to be used on many systems.

Comment: you may want to serve XML or JSON data then

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23163/discussion-between-ethan-and-alexander7567)